# Vue dynamic components not re rendering inside v-for loop when data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have dynamic table component where I can modify columns (ordering, adding new, removing columns). Table body looks like this:

```
<tr v-for="row in data" :key="row.id">
        <td v-for="column in columns" :key="column.slug">
          <component
            v-if="column.component"
            :is="column.component"
            v-bind="{ row: row, countries: row.reach }"
          />
          <template v-else>
            {{ row[column.slug] }}
          </template>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Everything works well except when I edit `data` (add new column or rearrange the order) then every component inside table body disappears and is not rendered. I tried to attach unique `:key` to `<component>` but was not able to make it work. When I inspect table body in Vue devtools I can see that components are inside just not rendered into DOM. When inspecting table body in chrome devtools I can see only `<!--function(e,n,r,o){return dn(t,e,n,r,o,!0)}-->` in place where component should be rendered. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you inspect `data` value after editing?

Comment: @Dmitry yes, everything is ok inside, but now I am getting some errors for each component: `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.` and `Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null"`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice `template` element inside. What is purpose of this element? Probably you should change it to simple `div`.

Comment: It was just a placeholder for `v-if` directive. I changed it to `div` but still I get the same result

Comment: Ok, then maybe you didn't registered some of the components, which you are trying to render via `:is="column.component"`. Or maybe some of your `column.component` values are `null`/`undefined` after editing? Try to wrap `component` element inside another `div` with `v-if="column.component"`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and didn't work. `data` after editing is fine, there is `component` property with proper data in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was passing Component object into `:is` directive instead of `string` with Component name. That's why it was not rendered properly.

Comment: Hi, could you please give me a working example? I have same issue.

Thanks

Comment: for example if you import your component into vue file like this: `import ExampleComponent from "./ExampleComponent";` then in your `:is` directive you need to pass it like this: `:is="'ExampleComponent'" not this: :is="ExampleComponent"`. In other words you need to pass component name, not component itself

Answer (score 3):

You are using duplicated keys. You should provide unique keys for all `v-for` elements inside the whole component. Try this (see `key` for every column):

```
      <tr v-for="row in data" :key="row.id">
        <td v-for="column in columns" :key="`${row.id}/${column.slug}`">
          <component
            v-if="column.component"
            :is="column.component"
            v-bind="{ row: row, countries: row.reach }"
          />
          <template v-else>
            {{ row[column.slug] }}
          </template>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Also when you are in development it is highly recommended to use Vue development mode. It will highlight errors like this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Turning development mode indeed helped me to fix some errors I didn't see before. But still, solution suggested by you is not working for me. I don't think it is an issue with duplicated keys